# Best practices when using schedulers

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I want to create a scheduler that access a stocks market service which returns a `.csv` file containing the latest transactions happen for a stock in a single day.

To do so, I intent to use `springframework` by creating a @scheduler that access the stocks market service in a fixed time, and them saves the .csv in a S3 repository.

I would like to hear from the community? Is it a nice approach? Should I use a different technology ? Is the springframework the most suitable tool for such scenario?

Please share your thoughts.
KR,
Arthur

Comment: It may depend on whether your application is horizontally scaled - @scheduler by default only knows about the current process so you could end up with multiple servers downloading the same file. We use quartz (along with Spring) and disallow concurrent execution - it means that whichever server picks up the job effectively locks it. This requires some external job control data eg in a database.

Answer (score 1):

Since you’re storing the data in AWS S3, it might be worth it to look at AWS Lambda for creating a serverless Java function for your scheduler. Lambda is easy to integrate with S3 and should be way cheaper (read free) to run in production.

I think that implementing this simple job with Spring and deploying it in a container or a fullsized VM is a bit overkill.